# Can not update scroll View height for a content view.bounds.height

Tags: swift

I have a code that contains a lot of different views and so on.. and I need to set ScrollView on it, then using func update scrollview height depends on contentView.frame.height

My code:

```
private lazy var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
        let scrollView = UIScrollView()
        scrollView.automaticallyAdjustsScrollIndicatorInsets = false
        scrollView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        return scrollView
    }()

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        configureUI()
    }
```

There is a configureUI func where I set all views

```
 private func configureUI() {
        view.addSubview(scrollView)
        scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
        contentView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.edges.equalToSuperview()
            make.width.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(1400) ?????? do I need it?
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(rocketImage)
        rocketImage.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        contentView.addSubview(backgroundForInfo)
        backgroundForInfo.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(rocketImage.snp.bottom).inset(50)
            make.left.right.equalToSuperview()
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        backgroundForInfo.addSubview(stackView)
        stackView.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalToSuperview().inset(40)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
        }
        
        backgroundForInfo.addSubview(launchButton)
        launchButton.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.top.equalTo(stackView.snp.bottom).offset(20)
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview().inset(20)
            make.height.equalTo(40)
        }
        
        view.addSubview(pageControl)
        pageControl.snp.makeConstraints { make in
            make.bottom.equalToSuperview()
            make.leading.trailing.equalToSuperview()
            make.height.equalTo(80)
        }

        updateScrollViewHeight()
    }
```

Func for checking height of contentView

```
private func updateScrollViewHeight() {
        view.layoutIfNeeded()
        let allViewsHeight = rocketImage.bounds.height + backgroundForInfo.bounds.height
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: view.bounds.width, height: allViewsHeight)
    }
```

If I set contentView Height 1400 I have empty spaces at the bottom of scrollView, if I set <1000 I do not see a lot of content.
So I use a func that calucalute scroll height

of course I can hardcode 1200 and everything will be all right, but what if I will not have some of "Stage" parameters (you can see it on screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Please provide images of the current result and the expected result.

Comment: Why do you need to change the scroll view's height? Please provide the current state and expected state of the result.

Comment: Added image and additional info

Comment: @kesape I suggest using table view it would be better in your scenario

Comment: @kesape Stage followed by three elements down will repeat based on the response, right? if yes then could you please tell me what will be the total height for these views?

Comment: total height is 1220, but can be lower